# How Can I Convert SQL Server 2012 Version 11.0.3000.0 to SQL Server 2012 Version 11.1.3000.0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, upgrade, service-pack

I have `SQL Server 2012` with version 11.0.3000.0 .

[image]

I need upgrade my version to `SQL Server 2012 SP1` because I need install Cumulation 4 in `Sql Server 2012 Cumulative Update 4` for use `PowerPivot` in `Multidimensional Database`.

Before install `Sql Server 2012 Cumulative Update 4` I need Upgrade my `SQL Server` to `Service Pack 1`.

How Can I Update My Version to SP1.

I sow [this Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575) and download `SQLServer2012SP1-KB2674319-x64-ENU.exe` and `SQLServer2012SP1-FullSlipstream-ENU-x64.iso` but this not work in my Server.

I have this error :

[image]

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server (NOT management studio)? Run select @@version and post the results - it looks like SP1 is already installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are already at Service Pack 1 (this is why `MSSQLSERVER` is checked and greyed out). 11.0.3000 and 11.1.3000 are essentially the same thing, different files just have different reasons for exposing a different number in the middle - that number is really not relevant to your problem.

So now you just need to [download and install the latest CU](https://sqlperformance.com/latest-builds/sql-server-2012) or, if you really want CU #4 specifically, you can [download that here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2833645) (just keep in mind  you are missing a boatload of fixes if you limit yourself to that update).

P.S. you check the version of SQL Server by opening a query window and running:

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

The method you're using now checks the version of Management Studio - these are client tools that can be older *or newer* than the server service itself.

Comment: my sql server version is : Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
but When I run SP1 CU #8 I get this error : The version of SQL Server instance Shared Component does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product version is 11.0.2100.60, and the expected SQL Server version is 11.1.3000.0.

Comment: @loup then that is not the same server or instance that the screen shot in your question is attempting to patch. If your server is at 2100 then that is RTM and you need to apply SP1 first. You won't get that validation error applying SP1 to an RTM instance. Are you trying to apply the service pack and/or cumulative update to a server from your workstation?

Comment: merci. it work. i first run service pack 1 and then U8

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the download page on service packs, there are a lot of details.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35575

Thus, SP1 install contains CU1 and cu2.

Are you sure the SQL server engine is installed?

I did a bunch of checking.  Not too much information on this error.

First place to start is the event logs and sql server error logs.

Please check for more information (details) on this error.

Comment: I am sure that SQL server engine is installed. and my error is : there are no sql server instance or shared features that can be updated on this computer.